# What is the correct meaning for the acronym PPP?

Tags: acronyms

Currently reading [**this article**](https://www.yahoo.com/money/coronavirus-stimulus-white-house-ups-offer-ahead-of-pelosi-tuesday-deadline-143916866.html), there is a line, says,

> “We've increased our offer up to almost $1.9 trillion,” Meadows told reporters on Monday morning. “[The president] is willing to give some additional money in terms of direct payments, he's willing to give some additional money in terms of **PPP** to restaurants and hotels and small businesses.”

> What does PPP stand for? May be Parent Partner Program from [**here**](https://abbreviations.woxikon.com/en/ppp)?

Answer (score 2):

The PPP in that article refers to the [Paycheck Protection Program](https://www.sba.gov/funding-programs/loans/coronavirus-relief-options/paycheck-protection-program), a loan program run by the [U.S. Small Business Administration (SBA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_Business_Administration). As per [their website](https://www.sba.gov/funding-programs/loans/coronavirus-relief-options/paycheck-protection-program):

> An SBA loan that helps businesses keep their workforce employed during the Coronavirus (COVID-19) crisis.

> The Paycheck Protection Program is a loan designed to provide a direct incentive for small businesses to keep their workers on the payroll.
>
> SBA will forgive loans if all employee retention criteria are met, and the funds are used for eligible expenses.

Comment: I'm sorry for the help. But I am sorry again I can't choose yours because other answer delivered the same answer...

Answer (score 1):

In this context, PPP stands for Paycheck Protection Program:

> The **Paycheck Protection Program (PPP)** is a $669-billion business loan program established by the 2020 US Federal government Coronavirus Aid, Relief, and Economic Security Act (CARES Act) to help certain businesses, self-employed workers, sole proprietors, certain nonprofit organizations, and tribal businesses continue paying their workers.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paycheck_Protection_Program

The article you linked actually explains this, but oddly, it's ["below the fold"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/below_the_fold).

> The bill, likely to be almost identical to the one that failed in the Senate in September, includes funding for the Payroll Protection Program (PPP), extra unemployment benefits, money for schools, and liability protections for businesses.

I had to click the "Story Continues" button near the bottom of the page to find this sentence.

Comment: I'm sorry for the help. But I am sorry again I can't choose yours because other answer delivered the same answer...

Comment: >The article you linked actually explains this, but oddly, it's "below the fold". hmmm....sorry.

Comment: @Kentaro, no reason to apologize.  The other answer was written at the same time as mine and since mine is a duplicate, I contemplated deleting it but since it included that quotation from the article, I thought it was worth keeping.